# Auto Increment If Duplicate Column in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table of items with primary column `id AUTO_INCREMENT`. Each item has a `type` (for the sake of example, types can be `apple` `orange` or `banana`) and some column `data`. How can I make a column `iteration`, which would on insertion of a new item be the incrementing value/id for that specific type of item?

Also since the table is already filled with data, how can I update the existing data to follow that pattern, in order of `time_added`.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `items` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `iteration` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `type` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `data` binary(16) NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE `items`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `unique_iteration` (`type`,`data`) USING BTREE;
```

Comment: @lad2025 There are more columns than that, which will be different for items of same `type`.

Comment: you can have only one auto_increment per table. if you want per-field incrementing values, you'll have to implement those yourself.

Comment: @MarcB I am aware of that, it would effectively be an auto_increment field for the specific type in question.

Comment: I think `INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` may help you here. You would need an unique key on type. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: @dan08 I don't want to update anything, there are more columns than mentioned in the question so even if two items have the same `type` they will have different values for the other columns.

Comment: @dan08 what record do you plan to update?

Comment: **IF** you're using myisam or bdb tables, mysql does allow secondary incrementing fields, if those fields are part of a composite index: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html. search for `For MyISAM and BDB tables you can specify AUTO_INCREMENT`

Comment: @MarcB Would I have to get rid of the `id` column (or rather, the `id` column would become the `AUTO_INCREMENT` of the composite index and I would have no column for the `id` of the row)?

Comment: no idea. never used that functionality before.

Comment: post your current table definition please?

Comment: @Alex http://pastebin.com/wuVur5qZ

Comment: @Alex Sorry my mistake, the `unique_iteration` index should just be with column `type`

Comment: @Alex Ignore last comment, it is actually meant to have both `type` and `data` in `unique_iteration`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set a trigger function against your `items` table:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER item_insert BEFORE INSERT ON items
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF (NEW.iteration IS NULL OR NEW.iteration=0) THEN
SET NEW.iteration = (SELECT 1+MAX(iteration) FROM items WHERE type=NEW.type);
END IF;
END; //
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Ended up going with @Marc B's suggestion of a composite primary index but this answers the original question, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very basic solution, but it actually should do what you requested:

```
INSERT INTO items
(SELECT null,CASE WHEN 'banana' NOT IN(SELECT type FROM items) THEN MAX(iteration) + 1 ELSE (SELECT increment FROM items WHERE type='banana') END,other_values,other_values 
FROM items)
```

The first value in `SELECT` needs to be `null` since you want it to remain as `auto_increment`. The Second value evaluates whether your new type (banana in this case) is `NOT IN` your types-columns. If so it adds 1 to your max `iteration` value `ELSE` it sets the value which is already associated with banana

So if you add a type banana and there is no banana in it, It should increment the max vaule of increment. If there is already a banana in your table it should give the banana the increment vaule which is associated with banana.

EDIT: 
Sorry, forgot about the second part of your request where you want to update your data based on time_added:

```
 BEGIN
        DECLARE col_id INT DEFAULT 1;
        DECLARE stepLoopDone BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE;
        DECLARE counter INT DEFAULT 1;
        DECLARE col_type SMALLINT(6) DEFAULT 1;

        DECLARE ORDER_CURSOR CURSOR FOR

            SELECT id, type
            FROM items
            ORDER BY time_added ASC;

        DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET stepLoopDone = TRUE;
        OPEN ORDER_CURSOR;

        myLoop: LOOP
            FETCH ORDER_CURSOR INTO col_id, col_type;

            IF stepLoopDone THEN
                LEAVE myLoop;
            END IF;

            /*YOUR UPDATE COMMAND*/
            UPDATE items
            SET increment = counter
            WHERE id = col_id
            AND type = col_type
            /*YOUR UPDATE COMMAND*/

            SET counter = counter + 1;

        END LOOP;

        CLOSE ORDER_CURSOR;
END
```

Use this second script with caution. Since i can't test it with your environment i'm not 100% sure what is does to your data. Maybe you should do a backup and test it then. 
I made a small test-table on my machine and it worked.